# Prove $\sin(x)+ \sin(x+a) + \sin(x+2a) + \sin(x+3a) + \sin(x+4a) = 0$ , given $a = 72^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove
$$\sin(x)+ \sin(x+a) + \sin(x+2a) + \sin(x+3a) + \sin(x+4a)=0 $$
given $a=72^\circ$

From what I know, I have to apply $\sin(\alpha+\beta)= \sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$

But this alone is not enough, am I lacking a crucial formula somewhere?

Comment: I would think of this as the imaginary part of $e^{ix}+e^{i(x+a)}+\cdots$.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [How can we sum up sin and cos series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $y(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4)=y(z^5-1)/(z-1)$.

What if $y=e^{ix}$ and $z=e^{ia}$?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the first and the fifth, the second and the fourth, and  finally the third, you will have

\begin{align}
\sin x + \sin (x+4a) + \sin (x+a) + \sin (x+3a) +\sin (x+2a) &=0\\ 
2\sin\frac{2x+4a}{2}\cos\frac{-4a}{2}+2\sin\frac{2x+4a}{2}\cos\frac{-2a}{2}+\sin (x+2a) &=0\\
\sin(x+2a)(2 \cos 2a + 2 \cos a + 1) &=0
\end{align}

As $x$ is unknown, then the second factor that must be zero. I will use a magic non-zero factor $\cos a -1$  here.

\begin{align}
2 \cos 2a + 2 \cos a + 1 &=0\\
4\cos^2 a +2\cos a -1&=0\\
(\cos a -1)(4\cos^2 a +2\cos a -1)&=0\\
4\cos^3 a  - 2\cos^2 a - 3\cos a +1 &=0\\
2\cos^2 a -1 &= 4\cos^3 a  - 3\cos a \\
\cos 2a &=\cos 3a\\
\cos 2a &= \cos (360^\circ -3a)\\
2a &=360^\circ -3a\\
5a&=360^\circ\\
a&=72^\circ
\end{align}